# Entity Framework 6.1.3 and SQL Server CE 4.0 - Code First Setup a password to protect sdf file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce-4

I am using `Entity Framework 6.1.3` along with `SQL Server CE 4.0`. Is there anyway to put a password on the generated `sdf` file the first time it is created?

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SQLCompactTest" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|SqlCeTest.sdf;Password=aaa;" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I try to add a Password field in my connection string but it does not add a password to the `sdf` file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `Password` field in the connection string DOES add a password to the created `sdf`. You just have to make sure the connectionstring is used by entityframework, which tripped me over.